# How to override services coupling caused by IdentityServer3.accesstokenvalidation

Tags: microservices, access-token, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have an identityserver4 which validates tokens sent along with the requests my APIs receive.

To do that I am using identityserver3.accesstokenvalidation.

In startup:

```
 JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
       Authority = Configurations.AuthorizationAuthority,
    });
```

Now I might face cases where server running identityserver4  is shortly (multiple seconds) unavailable.

If this happens the service containing my APIs will not be able to run saying that:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

I want my API service to start even if IdentityServer server is not running, is there some kind of configuration Identityserver3.accesstokenvalidation provides to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `DelayLoadMetadata` to `true`.

Comment: Is it necessary to use certificate in identity server 4 because i am getting this error :Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:33132/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.